# Remove blank space at the end of the ticket: Python Escpos

Tags: python-escpos

I have a printer: the PRINTER TG2460HIII USB RS232 CUTTER EJECTOR (915CG040400300)

I use Python Escpos

I have a problem:

The printed ticket has a lot of blank space at the end, about 5cm

Is it possible to define the maximum size of the ticket? I want to save paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a minimum ticket length:

```
_raw(b"\x1d\xe8\x20\x38")
```